# changing the htaccess file in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, upload

I want to change the maximum file upload size in my website, for this i'm going to add some code lines in my .htaccess file.

i have searched in google and i got the lines of code to add in .htaccess file. But i don't know exactly were to add that lines of code .

Below is the lines of code currently in my .htaccess file

code below

```
# -FrontPage-
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>

<Limit POST PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all`enter code here`
</Limit>

AuthName www.mysite.com
AuthUserFile /www/htdocs/domains/s11/01712/www.mysite.com/webdocs/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /www/htdocs/domains/s11/01712/www.mysite.com/webdocs/_vti_pvt/service.grp
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Here is the code to add

```
php_value post_max_size                  50M
php_value upload_max_filesize            50M
```

how to add this lines of code in .htaccess file and where??

Please help  me..

Thanks

Comment: Since those are php.ini values, it might be simpler to just call ini_set() if the function isn't locked down. ( http://www.php.net/ini_set )

Comment: I think php script will reject the file because of its size before processing the php code (i.e. way before reaching the ini_set line)

Comment: You can't set those settings with ini_set() because they are applied before your script runs a single line.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads and note the value of the "Changeable" column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the lines to the end of .htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size  50M
```

Comment: Keep in mind that certain web host providers prevent values like these from being overruled by .htaccess files.

Comment: therefore after making the changes, double check if the settings are applied by inspecting the output of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` (look at local value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size)